# Unity: Как добавить код в скрипт с помощью Input Field?

Tags: c#, unity3d, input

Я создаю что-то вроде компилятора в своей программе(см. рис. 1). Мне нужно делать так что когда я пишу что-то в Input Field, оно подключился к скрипте и стал кодом(см. рис. 2). **Как мне это сделать?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать это не в редакторе юнити, а на какой-либо платформе - ничего не получится. Единственный выход - разбирайте ваш "код" как строку и руками понимайте, какие команды есть в вводе. Иными словами пишите "транслятор"

Comment: @vmchar ну такой вариант я уже придумал) но неужели нельзя делать как в php там спокойно можно импортировать код

Comment: php - интерпретируемый, а C# компилируемый. А в случае с Unity на мобильных платформах - C# вообще перегоняется в С++ и дальше компилируется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# script engine for Unity3D
https://github.com/SoapCode/UCompile

Альтернатива:
https://github.com/aeroson/mcs-ICodeCompiler

Платная альтернатива:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/82084

Еще одна платная альтернатива:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/c-eval-56706

Еще полезно будет почитать: 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130268/how-do-i-compile-a-c-script-at-runtime-and-attach-it-as-a-component-to-a-game-o

> ОСОБЕННО Warning